# Load local (unserializable) objects on workers

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm trying to use Dataflow in conjunction with Tensorflow for predictions. Those predictions are happening on the workers and I'm currently loading the model through `startup_bundle()`. Like here:

```
class PredictDoFn(beam.DoFn): 
    def start_bundle(self):
        self.model = load_model_from_file()
    def process(self, element):
        ...
```

My current problem is that even if I process 1000 elements, the `startup_bundle()` function is called multiple times (at least 10) and not once per worked as I've hoped. This slows down the pipeline significantly because the model needs to be loaded many times and it takes every time 30 seconds.

**Are there any ways to load the model on the workers on initialisation and not every time in the `start_bundle()`?**

Thanks in advance!
Dimitri

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest thing would be for you to add an `if self.model is None: self.model = load_model_from_file()`, and this may not reduce the number of times your model is reloaded.

This is because DoFn instances are not *currently* reused across bundles. This means that your model will be *forgotten* after every work item is executed.

You could also create a `global` variable where you keep the model. This would reduce the amount of reloads, but it would be really unorthodox (though it may solve your use case).

---

A global variable approach should work something like this:

```
class MyModelDoFn(object):
  def process(self, elem):
    global my_model
    if my_model is None:
      my_model = load_model_from_file()
    yield my_model.apply_to(elem)
```

An approach that relies on a thread-local variable would look like so. Consider that this will load the model once per thread, so the number of times your model is loaded depends on runner implementation (it will work in Dataflow):

```
class MyModelDoFn(object):
  _thread_local = threading.local()
  @property
  def model(self):
    model = getattr(MyModelDoFn._thread_local, 'model', None)
    if not model:
      MyModelDoFn._thread_local.model = load_model_from_file()

    return MyModelDoFn._thread_local.model

  def process(self, elem):
    yield self.model.apply_to(elem)
```

I guess you can load the model from the `start_bundle` call as well.

**Note**: This approach is very unorthodox, and is not guaranteed to work in newer versions, nor all runners.

Comment: thanks for your suggestions Pablo! If you say the DoFn is not reused across bundles, I don't quite understand how `if self.model is None: self.model = load_model_from_file()` could possibly help? I would like to create a `global` variable but how would I do it? In my understanding I can't load it in the main session because it will fail to be serialised which is the requirements for `save_main_session = True` in the pipeline options. Is it possible to create a "worker global object" which is not instantiated in the main session?

Comment: It wouldn't - it's just that in the future, DoFn instances will start being reused across bundles (no ETA as of now). Also, I'll try to get back to you with a global variable example.

Comment: amazing, thanks a lot Pablo. Will give it a try today.